# What is '$add' functionality in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am new to angularJs, and am in the process of migrating an 0.9 versioned angularJs app to 1.0.5 version. I am stuck at a function named '$add' called on an array. 
I have searched in the docs for hours, but no use. Can anyone enlighten me regarding this? Also will be nicer to understand the significance/specialty of '$xxx' keyword usage within angular.

Comment: It was removed in 0.10.6. AngularJS changelog describes all the breaking changes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0106-bubblewrap-cape-2012-01-17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `$add` function was removed. You can replace it by the native Array `push()` function (they were basically the same).

Regarding the usage of `$`, the angularjs [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#angular_namespace) states:

> To prevent accidental name collision, Angular
>   prefixes names of objects which could potentially collide with $.
>   Please do not use the $ prefix in your code as it may accidentally
>   collide with Angular code.